# Kafka remove duplicate messages

Tags: apache-kafka

We had an out of memory error that caused hundreds of millions of duplicate messages to get added to a topic. Is there a way to pause all services and repair the topic and remove the duplicates? Kafka newbie here...

Answer (score 1):

Kafka records are immutable, meaning you cannot delete or update records. Kafka partitions are append-only structures.

But if you are using `delete retention policy` for topic and if these duplicate messages have the same keys, you can remove duplicate messages by updating `delete.retention.ms` configuration to a small number. This is called log compaction. Again, this only works if duplicate messages have the same keys.

If they do not have the same keys, I guess what you can do is:

- Consume all records from this topic into memory or a data store.
- Identify duplicate messages and remove them.
- Delete your topic.
- Recreate your topic.
- Produce unique messages to your topic.
- Let your application listen to the topic again.

Or you can also do this:

- Consume all records from this topic into memory or a data store.
- Identify duplicate messages and remove them.
- Produce unique messages into a new topic.
- Let your application listen to the newly created topic.
- Delete old topic.

But data loss should be carefully considered while doing this process.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I could set offset for each consumer as well, to be the last item, providing they were at the last offset before all this?

Comment: Yes, you could just set offsets too, but you should be careful doing that because then any messages in between which are not duplicate will not be processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use compact topic([cleanup.policy = compact](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_cleanup.policy)) to  reduce the memory, but  you can't get unique record using this config.